# Python testing. raw_input testing

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I have a python function that asks if user wants to use current file, or select a new one. I need to test it. Here is the function:

```
def file_checker(self):
    file_change = raw_input('If you want to overwite existing file ?(Y/N) ')

    if (file_change == 'y') or (file_change == 'Y') or (file_change == 'yes'):
        logging.debug('overwriting existing file')

    elif file_change.lower() == 'n' or (file_change == 'no'):
        self.file_name = raw_input('enter new file name: ')
        logging.debug('created a new file')
    else:
        raise ValueError('You must chose yes/no, exiting')
    return os.path.join(self.work_dir, self.file_name)
```

I've donr the part when user selects yes, but I dont know how to test the 'no' part:

```
def test_file_checker(self):
    with mock.patch('__builtin__.raw_input', return_value='yes'):
        assert self.class_obj.file_checker() == self.fname
    with mock.patch('__builtin__.raw_input', return_value='no'):
    #what should I do here ?
```

Comment: Incidentally, wouldn't it make more sense to loop until the user selects "yes" or "no", instead of immediately exiting if the user makes a mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [`mock` documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#calling):

> **If `side_effect` is an iterable then each call to the mock will return
>   the next value from the iterable.** The side_effect can also be any
>   iterable object. Repeated calls to the mock will return values from
>   the iterable (until the iterable is exhausted and a StopIteration is
>   raised):

So the `no` part can be expressed as follow:

```
with mock.patch('__builtin__.raw_input', side_effect=['no', 'file2']):
    assert self.class_obj.file_checker() == EXPECTED_PATH
```